# How to integrate bootstrap into jekyll

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jekyll, jekyll-bootstrap

To the default minima template how will you integrate bootstrap?
What I did is download bootstrap sass version. Added bootstrap folder and scss file to _sass folder. Then added two lines to asset/main.scss files to import bootstrap and variables.scss
Do I need to add any js, min.css lines to head portion?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Jekyll to compile bootstrap sass files:

- Add javascript before the closing  tag
- Add `css/styles.scss` (with triple dashes at the beginning), it will generate `css/styles.css`
- Add it to the `<head>` section

I've wrote a detailed [guide to customize Bootstrap 4 in Jekyll](https://simpleit.rocks/how-to-add-bootstrap-4-to-jekyll-the-right-way/).

Comment: Can you show how to add bootstrap 3 as 4 in developing state

Comment: The same but you need to use the sass version of Bootstrap (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass) In BS4 it is the default.